# Update same record at once by LinqToEntity

Tags: c#, wcf, linq-to-entities

I'm using LinqToEntity to decrease Stock quantity.
And this can be called multiply at once by several clients.

When I'm using ExecuteSqlCommand (Query), actual result is ok.
I tried to run below code with 2 client program at once.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var q1 = Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("update InventoryContainer set QuantityCurrent = QuantityCurrent - {1}, where RawID = {0}", 1, 1);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
}

Original : 0
ExpectedResult : -2000
ActualResult : -2000
```

but when I'm using LinqToEntity and SaveChanges() and run with 2 client program at once, actual result is very different.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var ic = InventoryContainer.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RawID == 1);
    ic.QuantityCurrent -= 1;
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    SaveChanges();
}

Original : 0
ExpectedResult : -2000
ActualResult : -1032
```

I need to run this with LinqToEntity because a lot of data handling is performing with LinqToEntity and want to call SaveChanges() only 1 time in the transaction.

Comment: what do you mean by two clients at once?

Comment: Two PC (Client) had performed those source code to database at same time

Comment: Have you considered the possibility of concurrency issue?

Comment: Yes but it throws Exception but I'd like to execute like Query and no exception